# Error consuming rest API in .net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, json.net

I'm trying to consume a rest API but I'm getting the next error:

> Exception Details: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Unexpected JSON
>   token while reading DataTable: StartObject

also, if changing endpoint I get:
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

which is pointing to this line of code:

```
var table = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(data);
```

not really sure how to fix it? Anyone can spot what the error is or how to fix it?...

thanks..

My controller is:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> About()
    {
        string url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/region/africa";

        using (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var table = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(data);

                System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView gView = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
                gView.DataSource = table;
                gView.DataBind();
                using (System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter())
                {
                    using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw))
                    {
                        gView.RenderControl(htw);
                        ViewBag.ReturnedData = sw.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return View();
```

Comment: What does your json (`data`) look like?

Comment: it's kind long to paste here in the comments, but if you go to the URL you can see it

Comment: Why deserialize it into a datatable?  That JSON looks nothing like a datatable would.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be deserializing into a `DataTable`.  A `DataTable` is a generic, in-memory representation of some relational data.  With the following deserialization lines of code you have:

```
var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var table = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<System.Data.DataTable>(data);
```

you are asking your .NET code to go grab some data from the internet and turn that string of data into an in-memory representation of relational data, when, at this point, it's really only a string of characters.

You should create a model of a country with the properties that are returned from the API you're querying.

You can then deserialize that data and play with it in .NET by doing something like the following:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<MyCountryModel>>(data);
```

Comment: The exact data I'm expecting back is: {
  "error": 0,
  "Logs": [
    {
      "ProdLoggerIdx": "1",
      "OfficeID": "1112222",
      "Agent": "user1",
      "CommandSent": "JI2345XY/GS",
      "HostResponse": "A-SIGN COMPLETE/10NO",
      "CommandSentDate": "2016-11-14T12:14:01.000Z",
      "CommandReceivedDate": "2016-11-14T12:14:01.000Z"
    },
so I should create a model according to this specs, right? how can I set the field "Logs" for that model, kinda confused ....

Comment: @RolandoF Logs is an array of strings.  So the property is a `string[]`.

Comment: The logs would not be an array of strings.  An array of strings would like like `["ProdLoggerIdx", "1", "OfficeID", "1112222"]`, but it's JSON.  


@RolandoF the Logs property would be a list of a type that you create to match what the JSON returns. By the looks of it, this model would have a property named ProdLoggerIdx, type of string, a property named OfficeId, type of string, etc.  It's also got two DateTimes in there.  

As long as you make an object with the correct property names and types, Json.NET will handle the serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @steamrolla I created my model with : public string userId { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string body { get; set; } , but still getting error, maybe because I still need the string array?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments I got to solve the model problem and defined it like this,....thanks

```
public class Log2
{
    public string error { get; set; }
    public Log3[] Logs { get; set; }
}

 public class Log3
{
    public string ProdLoggerIdx { get; set; }
    public string OfficeID { get; set; }
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    public string CommandSent { get; set; }
    public string HostResponse { get; set; }
    public string CommandSentDate { get; set; }
    public string CommandReceivedDate { get; set; }

}
```